# javascript setTimeout(); doesn't work on linux (firefox)

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox, animation, settimeout

I am making an animation, which uses the setTimeout(); function in javascript. The animation works well on chrome, firefox, even on  my smartphone. The only problem is with firefox on ubuntu.

Console is giving me an error:

```
ReferenceError: loop is not defined @ file:///home/nigga/GitHub/imgdrop/imgdrop.js:45
```

The code:

```
function loop()
{
    regenerate();
    animate();

    setTimeout("loop()", 1000/fps);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I tried what @LOL suggested, which works on linux, but doesnt work back on windows (firefox and IE).

Comment: Maybe firefox cached your scripts?

Answer (score 2):

```
function loop()
{
    regenerate();
    animate();
setTimeout(function() {loop();}, 1000);
}
```

OR

```
function loop()
    {
        regenerate();
        animate();
    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Why create an anonymous function which does nothing but call another function without arguments?

Comment: @LOL — Well, you're not using it as a closure, and you could use the `loop` function as an argument directly.

Comment: @Quentin i always tried this and works fine. do you want to say that i have to use `setTimeout(loop();, 1000);`

Comment: Well, yes, it works fine, it is just more work then needed and bloats up the code to make it harder to read. No, that calls `loop` and passes its return value to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(loop, 1000);`